# Function to list ORG buffers only

Tags: org-mode

I am trying to achieve a Helm-like interface for selecting Org mode buffers, but it's not working:

```
(defun helm-org-buffers ()
  "Use Helm to select an Org mode buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-buffers
         (cl-remove-if-not (lambda (buffer)
                             (with-current-buffer buffer
                               (eq major-mode 'org-mode))))
                           (buffer-list))))
    (helm :sources (helm-build-sync-source "Org Buffers"
                     :candidates (mapcar #'buffer-name org-buffers)
                     :action #'switch-to-buffer)
          :prompt "Select Org buffer: ")))
```

Any help welcome!

Comment: One detail: don't use `with-current-buffer`, but `(eq (buffer-local-value 'major-mode buffer) 'org-mode)`.

Comment: Why? Care to expand?

Comment: I get error: `let' bindings can have only one value-form: org-buffers, (cl-remove-if-not (lambda (buffer) (eq (buffer-local-value 'major-mode buffer) 'org-mode) (eq major-mode 'org-mode))), (buffer-list)

Answer (score 0):

When you replace the block `with-current-buffer` with a call to `buffer-local-value` it works immediately.

```lisp
(defun helm-org-buffers ()
  "Use Helm to select an Org mode buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-buffers
         (cl-remove-if-not (lambda (buffer)
                             (eq (buffer-local-value 'major-mode buffer) 'org-mode))
                           (buffer-list))))
    (helm :sources (helm-build-sync-source "Org Buffers"
                     :candidates (mapcar #'buffer-name org-buffers)
                     :action #'switch-to-buffer)
          :prompt "Select Org buffer: ")))
```

I can't give a better reason than "that's how I see it everywhere in the source code", so let's hope someone can explain it to us.